# Ruby on Rails - Run callback code after initialize method in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, spree

I am using Ruby on Rails 5.2 with ruby 2.4.2p198

Let's say I have a controller (for example this: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/3-6-stable/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/reports_controller.rb) and I want to run some code using a callback after the `initialize` method.

For this, I've created a decorator (for example: `reports_controller_decorator.rb`) and added the method that I want to run in the `after_action`callback.

My issue is that this works (the method is called) if I use the callback on the `index` method, but it doesn't work if I pass the `initialize` method as parameter in the callback:

```rb
# It works (note the index method in the callback parameter)
Spree::Admin::ReportsController.class_eval do
  after_action :post_initialize, only: :index

  def post_initialize
    Spree::Admin::ReportsController.add_available_report!(:custom_sales_total)
  end
end
```

```rb
# It doesn't (note the initialize method in the callback parameter)
Spree::Admin::ReportsController.class_eval do
  after_action :post_initialize, only: :initialize

  def post_initialize
    Spree::Admin::ReportsController.add_available_report!(:custom_sales_total)
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Is possible to run callbacks after the `initialize` method?

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you make `post_initialize` a `before_action`? It seems like it would occur after initialization, but before the named action(s). No?

Comment: Per your suggestion I have changed the callback, but the result seems to be the same.

Comment: In the link you provided, I don't see `class_eval do` appended to the class name. Am I missing that? It looks rather unusual (perhaps something extra clever that I am unaware of). Oh, and you did `before_action :post_initialize` (limiting it to specific actions as appropriate)?

Comment: The `class_eval` is a way to make changes (override or add methods) to an existent class. In this case, this class is part of a gem that I want to modify.

Comment: When you're referring to using `initialize`, is this an action or are you calling it on an instance (e.g. `Report.new` will fire the report's `initialize` method)?

Comment: I am calling this on an instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses the `before`, `after` and `around` `_action` filters only on ["actions"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions). Restfull controllers should only define 7 [actions](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=5):

1. show
2. index
3. edit
4. update
5. new
6. create
7. destroy

Usually controllers don't define an `initialize` action, although they do inherit an `initialize` method from their parent class. That is to say there is no route in rails that will go to the initialize method of a controller. Since there is no `initialize` action to run when you open the `index` action of `Spree::Admin::ReportsController` the `post_initialize` filter is never run.

Rails has no after_initialize callback for its controllers, only for its models. If you want to add code to the initialize function of the controller you can reopen the class and overwrite the initializer (not recomended) or subclass the controller and call super in the new initializer and add you code afterwords.

```
Spree::Admin::ReportsController.class_eval do
  def initialize
    super
    Spree::Admin::ReportsController.add_available_report!(:custom_sales_total)
  end
end
```

or

```
class CustomSalesTotalController < Spree::Admin::ReportsController
  def initialize
    super
    Spree::Admin::ReportsController.add_available_report!(:custom_sales_total)
  end
end
```

Which is actually what Spree is doing [under the hood](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/bada1e83a96e08dd08a0b65c0f0e627964c9d15a/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/reports_controller.rb).

Comment: I have tried both. The first completely replaces the method in the decorated controller (the one from Spree), and the second doesn't get executed. I guess I will have to override the `initialize` method.

Comment: For the second one to run you will need to change the route in the config/routes.rb so that it uses the subclass controller. I'm guessing spree sets up its own routes but you could add it in the file before the spree routes since the routes get evaluated in order and the first to match is the one that runs.